# Issue passing go test command line arguments via launch.json

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, command-line-arguments

I'm looking to debug a Go test which works fine using the console. However, I can't figure out how to pass the arguments in correctly via launch.json.

Console:

```
(base) me@US-M1P-TB e2e % pwd                                              
/Users/me/workspace/tests/e2e
(base) me@US-M1P-TB e2e % go test -run TestRankingExperiment -args -n LOCAL
*works as expected*
```

Attempt 1:

```
    {
        "name": "Rerank Experiment",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "test",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/tests/e2e",
        "args": ["-run TestRankingExperiment -args -n LOCAL"]
    }
```

Result: `flag provided but not defined: -run TestRankingExperiment -args -n LOCAL`

Attempt 2:

```
    {
        "name": "Rerank Experiment",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "test",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/tests/e2e",
        "env": {},
        "args": ["-run", "TestRankingExperiment", "-args", "-n", "LOCAL"]
    }
```

Result: `flag provided but not defined: -run`

For context `TestRankingExperiment` is the name of a test case inside `tests/e2e/ranking_experiment_test.go`. `ranking_experiment_test.go` can't be run directly because it is an e2e test which relies on a test wrapper being run first. Not sure on the details, but `tests/e2e/main_test.go` appears to be involved.